# Calculate a 3D trajectory by start point, end point and height

Tags: c#, game-physics

I've already figured out how to make a 3D trajectory using a start point and an angle.
However, I am trying to make a trajectory from a start point, an end point, and a height.

I tried taking the approach of a parabola on a 2D plane in a 3D space. I calculated the Prabola's A, B, and C values as well as the plane it's on given 3 points on the Parabola.
However, I've had a few complications with this sort of calculation, I assume it has to do with the inability to properly calculate a Z-axis without a plane but I cannot tell.

Other than a 2D parabola on a plane google did not provide another possible answer and a 3D trajectory yields a formula using a start point, an angle, and a power multiplier.

- **Is there any way to calculate a 3D trajectory given the start point, end point, and height?**

Appreciating your help

**Edit**:

My code to calculate a parabola using 3 points (in case someone would like to know how I've done that and perhaps fix what I've done wrong)

```
public Parabola(Vector3 pa, Vector3 pb, Vector3 pc)
        {
            this.pa = pa;
            this.pc = pc;
            float a1 = -pa.x * pa.x + pb.x * pb.x, b1 = -pa.x + pb.x, c1 = -pa.y + pb.y;
            float a2 = -pb.x * pb.x + pc.x * pc.x, b2 = -pb.x + pc.x, c2 = -pb.y + pc.y;
            float bm = -(b2 / b1), a3 = bm * a1 + a2, c3 = bm * c1 + c2;
            float a = c3 / a3, b = (c1 - a1 * a) / b1, c = pa.y - a * pa.x * pa.x - b * pa.x;
            this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c;
            plane = Vector3.Cross(pb - pa, pc - pa);
        }

public Vector3 GetPoint(float x) 
        {
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(pc.z - pa.z, pc.x - pa.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            float xs = Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * x, zs = Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * x;
            return new Vector3(xs, a * x * x + b * x + c, zs); 
        }

public Vector3 ProjectOn(float x) => Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(GetPoint(x), plane);
```

The result looks ok when it's only on 2 Axis, but not 3.
here are 2 images for demonstration:
[image: The correct one but only on 2 axis(start and end points' Z values are equal)]
[image: Incorrect, now on 3 axis(Z values not equal)]

Comment: you can draw infinitely many 3d trajectories, which passes through start point end point and height

Comment: I am aware of that, this is why I also want a maxHeight, the maxHeight is the highest point of the trajectory, which if you have its Y value, can be calculated, then you actually have 3 points

Comment: 3 points does not define a unique 3d trajectory, at most you can define a circle or an arc on that circle.

Comment: That is new to me... as far as I'm aware a trajectory is a parabola-like shape and I am pretty certain that there are 2 parabolas on every 3 points (one regular parabola and one parabola on the side). Or at least... that's what I know, perhaps I'm wrong.

In that case then, what is needed for me to determine a trajectory assuming I want a start and end points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, but it's kinda a workaround.

Before messing around with Parabolas in 3D, I messed around with linear equations in 3D.
Unlike parabolas, lines have a defined equation even in 3D(**Pn = P0 + t x V**)(Pn vector containing XYZ, P0 initial point containing XYZ, t float, V Vector3)

In addition, there's only **ONE** line that goes through 2 points, even in 3D.

I used that to make a trajectory that's made out of 2 points and a height.
I make a new point in the center of those two points and add the height value to the highest Y value of the points, thus creating an Apex.

then I use the same calculations as before to calculate the A, B, and C values that
a parabola with those 3 points would have had.

I made a method that takes in an X value and returns a Vector3 containing the point this X is on a linear equation, but instead, changing the vector's Y value based on the parabola's equation.

Practically creating an elevated line, I made something that looks and behaves perfectly like a 3D parabola.

If you're in C#, here is the code(images):
[image: Linear]

[image: Trajectory]

**FIX!!**

in the Linear's GetX(float x) method.
it should be:

```
public Vector3 GetX(float x) => => r0 + (x - r0.x)/v.x * v;
```

I made a slight mistake in the calculations which I noticed immediately and changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the second image, the parabola seems to be correct aside from being scaled incorrectly. Let's take a look at your code.

```
public Vector3 GetPoint(float x) 
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(pc.z - pa.z, pc.x - pa.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float xs = Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * x, zs = Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * x;
        return new Vector3(xs, a * x * x + b * x + c, zs); 
    }
```

I'm making a lot of assumptions here, but it seems like `x` is meant as a value that goes from 0.0 to 1.0, representing the start and end of the parabola, respectively. If so, you are determining the X and Z coordinates of this point based exclusively on the sine/cosine of the angle and `x`. This means that the values `xs` and `zs` should only ever be able to be between -1 and 1, limiting yourself to the confines of the unit circle.

The values `xs` and `zs` look like they need to be scaled by a factor `s` calculated by measuring the 2D distance of the start and end points when projected onto the XZ plane. This should stretch the parabola just enough to reach the end point.

Comment: but the cos and sin are multiplied by the X value which can be any value, the cos and sin of the angle is between 1 to -1, but the X value can be anything. The reason it doesn't work is because I assume the Z value based on the X value which is wrong, and I don't really have a way to make a parabola that takes account of both X and Z and yields a Y.. not one that I found... I have a solution however, I just found it, I will post it rn

Comment: Another reason this answer is not quite correct is because of the angle the picture is taken from... The parabola is not just smaller it is also rotated a little differently, even if you were to scale it up it wouldn't fit the dots