# Find an angle and velocity to launch the projectile with to reach a specific point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, projectile

I am trying to make a cannon that shoots a target located in a 3D world in Unity... I hava a `LaunchConfig` enum ->

```
public enum LauncherConfig
{
    CalculateNone = 0,
    CalculateAngle = 1,
    CalculateVelocity = 2,
    CalculateBoth = 3
}
```

When `CalculateAngle` is selected the user can input the Initial Velocity for the projectile and the angle the projectile needs to be launched at to reach the target has to be calculated.
Same for `CalculateVelocity`.
`CalculateNone` allows the user to input both the values and `CalculateBoth`  calculates both the values.

What equations do I use to calculate the values so that they line up, i.e. when `CalculateAngle` is selected the velocity calculated should be such that the projectile looks natural coming out of the barrel. Same for `CalculateBoth`, the angle should be calculated so that the velocity calculated will launch the projectile strait out the barrel and not any other direction.

I have my current location (Vector3), target location (Vector3).
The calculated angle will affect the x-rotation of the cannon.
The y-rotation is lined up with the target already so that it faces the target;

Here is the code for the class

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Launcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LauncherSettings settings = default;
    [SerializeField] private Transform target = default;
    private Transform partToRotateY;
    private Transform partToRotateX;
    private Transform projectileSpawnPosition;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    private void Awake()
    {
        partToRotateX = transform.GetChild(0);
        partToRotateY = transform.GetChild(1);
        projectileSpawnPosition = partToRotateX.GetChild(0);
        settings.inputController = new InputActions.Launcher();
        settings.inputController.Automatic.Launch.performed += _ => Shoot();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CalculateVelocity();
        CalculateAngle();
        LookAtTarget();
        Shoot();
    }
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        settings.inputController.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        settings.inputController.Disable();
    }

    private void LookAtTarget()
    {
        Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        y = lookRotation.eulerAngles.y;
        Quaternion rotationY = Quaternion.Euler(0f, y, 0f);
        Quaternion rotationX = Quaternion.Euler(-x, y, 0f);
        partToRotateY.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(partToRotateY.rotation, rotationY, Time.deltaTime * settings.rotationSpeed);
        partToRotateX.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(partToRotateX.rotation, rotationX, Time.deltaTime * settings.rotationSpeed);
    }

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;
    
    private void Shoot()
    {
        nextTimeToFire -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (!(nextTimeToFire <= 0f)) return;
        nextTimeToFire = 1 / settings.fireRate;
        var rb = Instantiate(settings.projectilePrefab, projectileSpawnPosition.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.velocity = velocity;
    }

    private void CalculateAngle()
    {
        if (settings.launcherConfig == LauncherConfig.CalculateVelocity ||
            settings.launcherConfig == LauncherConfig.CalculateNone)
        {
            x = Mathf.Clamp(settings.launchAngle, -20f, 80f);
        }
        else
        {
            var position = target.position;
            var position1 = transform.position;
            var dist = Math.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow((position.x - position1.x), 2) + Mathf.Pow((position.y - position1.y), 2));
            var a = Physics.gravity.y * Mathf.Pow((float) dist, 2) / (2 * Mathf.Pow(velocity.magnitude, 2));
            var b = (float) -dist;
            var c = position.z - position1.z + a;
            x = (float) Math.Atan2(QuadraticRoot(a, b, c), 1);
            Debug.Log(x);
        }
    }

    private void CalculateVelocity()
    {
        if (settings.launcherConfig == LauncherConfig.CalculateAngle ||
            settings.launcherConfig == LauncherConfig.CalculateNone)
        {
            velocity = partToRotateX.forward * settings.velocity;
        }
        else
        {
            float h;
            if (settings.launcherConfig == LauncherConfig.CalculateBoth && settings.calculateMaxHeight)
            {
                h = Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - partToRotateX.position.y * settings.maxHeightMultiplier);
            }
            else
            {
                h = settings.maxHeight;
            }

            var position = partToRotateX.position;
            var position1 = target.position;
            var gravity = Physics.gravity.y;

            var displacementY = position1.y - position.y;
            var displacementXZ = new Vector3 (position1.x - position.x, 0, position1.z - position.z);
            var time = Mathf.Sqrt(-2*h/gravity) + Mathf.Sqrt(2*(displacementY - h)/gravity);
            var velocityY = Vector3.up * Mathf.Sqrt (-2 * gravity * h);
            var velocityXZ = displacementXZ / time;

            velocity = velocityXZ + velocityY * -Mathf.Sign(gravity);
        }
    }
    
    private double QuadraticRoot(double a, double b, double c){
        double D = Math.Pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
        return (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    }
}
```

The LauncherSettings Class...

```
using Attributes.DrawIf;
using Attributes.DrawIfAndOr;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class LauncherSettings : ScriptableObject
{
    public InputActions.Launcher inputController;
    public LauncherConfig launcherConfig = LauncherConfig.CalculateVelocity;
    public GameObject projectilePrefab = default;
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float fireRate = 5f;
    [DrawIfAndOr(nameof(launcherConfig), LauncherConfig.CalculateAngle, LauncherConfig.CalculateNone)]
    public float velocity = 200f;
    [DrawIfAndOr(nameof(launcherConfig), LauncherConfig.CalculateVelocity, LauncherConfig.CalculateNone)]
    public float launchAngle = 0f;
    [DrawIf(nameof(launcherConfig), LauncherConfig.CalculateBoth)]
    public bool calculateMaxHeight = true;
    [DrawIf(nameof(calculateMaxHeight), false)]
    public float maxHeight;
    [DrawIf(nameof(calculateMaxHeight), true)]
    public float maxHeightMultiplier = 5f;
}
```

The `DrawIf` and `DrawIfAndOr` are attributes that hide the vaule in inspector if the first paramerter is equal to the other. You can completely ignore them. The calculation of Velocity is by
Sebastian Lague (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmtyQOKKmrMVaKuRXz02jbQ) in his Kinematic Equations (E03: ball problem) (https://youtu.be/IvT8hjy6q4o). The calculation of the angle is from an answer on my other question ([Find an angle to launch the projectile at to reach a specific point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376316/find-an-angle-to-launch-the-projectile-at-to-reach-a-specific-point)).

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks...

Comment: My calculus a bit rusty but vtcos(ang) = x. So i assume u know v as the initial velocity. T is the spent time flying ( you can define with the overall distance to simplify). x is where you land. So u can get ang = arcos(vt/x) or so I think. That's all with 0 friction.

Comment: Wait... so you want to determine the trajection based on start and end points? and for the cannon to change the strength and angle?

If that's case, I made a Trajection class that can determine a parabolic path using start point, end point and max height, if you'd like I'll send a link for it(It's on another StackOverflow thread)

Comment: @1Mangomaster1 Yeah that's basically what I want, but the values can change like I want to angle the cannon twice as much and want to calculate the velocity for that, the same for velocity, if I want it to have double the velocity the angle should change as well...

Comment: Well you can determine the height as I said you have the start point so I guess you can mess around with the start point and height to get the angle, and from there it will do the arc to the end point

Comment: Check out the solution I offered there, I put images of the code I made, it's kinda a workaround but it works perfectly well soo I guess that's good, also, I added a fix there that's not in the image soo note that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550864/calculate-a-3d-trajectory-by-start-point-end-point-and-height